# How to sum two strings and add to a list class?

Tags: c#

```cs
    class Asient
    {
        private List<String> letras = new List<String> {
          "A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","J"};

        private List<string> fila = new List<string> {
          "1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8"};

        private List<string> asientos= new List<string>();

        public Asient(){
            for (int i = 0; i < letras.Count; i++){
                for (int n = 0; n < letras.Count; n++){
                    string sillaletra = letras[i] + fila[n];
                    asientos.Add(sillaletra);
                }
            }
        }

        public List<string> GetAsientos(){
            return this.asientos;
        }
    }

    class Mainn
    {   
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Asient sillas = new Asient();
            sillas.GetAsientos();
        }
    }
```

And the code give me this **runtime error**:

```
Unhandled exception. System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. 
Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. (Parameter 'index')
  at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.get_Item(Int32 index)
  at A05CINE.Asient..ctor() in D:\Users\x\x\x\x\x\c#\x\x\x.cs:line 15
  at A05CINE.Mainn.Main(String[] args) in D:\Users\x\Desktop\x\x\x\c#\A05\x\x.cs:line 31
```

Does someone know how to fix that?

I tried using

```cs
asientos.Add(letras[i] + fila[n]);
string sillaletra = letras[i] + fila[n]; 
asientos.Add(sillaletra);
```

Comment: Thanks Shawn. It's too late for me, but you've saved others from sharing my fate.

Comment: You have more letters (9) than numbers (8). Also please translate and indent your questions to make easier to people help you. Debug before posting.

Comment: *"Some one know who to fix that?"* Yeah, don't attempt to access indexes that are greater than the length of the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems, you are looking for *Cartesian Join*, i.e. you want `List<string>` to be

```
  { "A1", "A2", ..., "A8", "B1", ..., "B8", ..., "J8" }
```

If it's your case, you can put a simple *Linq* query for this:

```
  using System.Linq;

  ... 

  public Asient() {
    asientos = letras
      .SelectMany(letter => fila.Select(digit => letter + digit))
      .ToList();
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

You have more letters than numbers, add

```
private List<string> fila= new List<string>{"1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"};
```

and it will work.

Comment: Thnk i appreciate your help <3, i solvet it by doing the correct for. if you see the for() i'm doing for() in for(), for the same list i that its way dosen't work.
sorry for my bad eng. @Hasse

Answer (score 1):

You are looping through the same length. Into your loop, both ends at position `letras.Count`, but list has not the same length.

Your loop should iterate over the length of each array like this:

```cs
for (int i = 0; i < letras.Count; i++)
{
    for (int n = 0; n < fila.Count; n++)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

Note that the first array goes from 0 to `letras.Count`.

And second goes from 0 to `fila.Count`.

Now, each position is iterated.